# Asymptotic complexity of generating permutation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I stumbled on this question while answering a question on stackoverflow.
A guy asked what the complexity of the following code was.

```
void permutation(String str){
   permutation(str,"");
}
void permutation(String str, String prefix){
  if(str.length()==0){
    System.out.println(prefix);
  } else{
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1);
         permutation(rem,prefix+str.charAt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

We should first notice that  each call to `String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1)` costs $O(n)$.
If we denote with $T(n)$ the cost of a call to `permutation` with an input of size $n$ then $$T(n) = n [n + T(n-1)]$$

because the cost of the body of the `for` in the `else` path is $n+T(n-1)$
in the  `else` path.

- What is (if one exists) a method for solving `T(n)`?

I have tried to expand $T(n)$ :
$$T(n) = n^2 + n(T(n-1) $$
$$= n^2 + n( (n-1)^2 + (n-1)T(n-2))
$$ 
$$= n^2 + n( (n-1)^2 + (n-1)[(n-2)^2+(n-2)T(n-3)])$$
$$=n^2 + n( (n-1)^2 + (n-1)(n-2)^2+(n-1)(n-2)T(n-3)])$$
$$=n^2 + n(n-1)^2 + n(n-1)(n-2)^2+n(n-1)(n-2)T(n-3)]) \ldots n!$$

which should be to 
$$ T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!(n-k)}{(n-k-1)!} $$

- This is where I am stuck. What is the value of that summation?

Since I was stuck I have tried to get an upper bound on  $T(n)$ reasoning as follows:

I know that there are $n!$ permutation and that in the recursion tree each of them is a leaf. For each leaf there is a path to the root of exactly length $n$. As an upper bound it is safe to assume that there  are not more than $n*n!$ nodes in the tree (no path from leaf to root share a node).
I know that node costs $O(n)$ cause of the `substring` call so the overall complexity is $O(n^2n!)$

- Is this approximation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting your sum as $$n!\sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{\ell}{(\ell-1)!}$$ you get from keeping the first term that $T(n)\geq n!\cdot 1$, and by majoring by $$n!\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{\ell}{(\ell-1)!}=n!\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{(\ell+1)}{\ell!} = 2e n!$$ that $T(n) \leq 2e n!$. So $T(n) = \Theta(n!)$.